# How to get only one document per subcollection in collection group query?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-admin

I have this Firestore data schema:

```
rootCol/{rootDoc}/subCol1/{doc1Type}
rootCol/{rootDoc}/subCol2/{doc2Type}
```

I want get all documents in `subCol1` where `rootDoc` contain `doc2Type` with specific field.

I know I can use simple `.where` call to get all `doc2Type` where `exampleField == ‘exampleString’` and then get path for find `SubCol1`.

BUT problem is `subCol2` can contain many `doc2Type` with `exampleField`. This mean my query will return many `doc2Type` and then cause my query to `subCol1/{doc1Type}` to be call multiple time.

How I can get only 1 document from every `subCol2` subcollection where `exampleField == ‘exampleString’`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a collection group query.  These queries consider all documents among all subcollections equally.  It can't "group" the documents by subcollection or let you apply per-subcollection filters.

You will have to either restructure your data to better support what you're trying to do, or write client code filter the results of the collection group query to find the single document in each subcollection by using the reference of each document to limit the results to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for reply! How I can filter result of collection group query if both doc will have very similar data?

Comment: That's entirely for you to decide.  I can't see your data, and I don't know which documents you want.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I think I have solution. There is one field which is different in the different doc in the same subcollection. So maybe I can do a subcollection group query with 2 `.where` filters?

Comment: Again, I can't see your data, so I can't make any recommendations.  If you have a new question, please post that separately with the code and data that isn't working the way you expect.